# is there any reason for writing a web crawler framework for Objective-C when there is framework for C language?

Tags: objective-c, web-crawler

i wanted to write a web crawler library for Objective-C ! but there is a library available for C language !

since we can compile C codes in our Objective-C projects in Xcode ! is there any reasonable purpose that we write a new library for Objective-C with itself syntax?

any performance ? or any reason ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure;  lots of reasons.

The primary reason is if you want to hook the web crawler into an Objective-C application.  For example, you might want to crawl the web and store results in Core Data for later local retrieval.   Writing an Objective-C API makes it that much easier.

Wrapping a C based API in Objective-C is very easy, too.  It is quite common to wrap C API in Objecitve-C to make the C based API that much easier to work with.  OO patterns naturally encapsulate the notion of "session" or "context" that are typically represented by awkwardly managed manual malloc()d structures in C;   those structures typically fit naturally into an Objective-C class.